# How can I show that $3x^2+3^x \ln (x) > 0 \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I prove that $3x^2+3^x \ln (x) > 0 \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

I am trying to prove that $x^3+3^x = 0$ has a unique solution. I proved that the solution exists using the Intermediate Value Theorem, and I proved that it is unique using the Mean Value Theorem.

Proof: Let $f(x) = x^3+3^x$. Let $f(a)=f(b)=0$ where $a \neq b$. WLOG, assume $a>b$. Then by the MVT, $\exists c \in (a,b)$ s.t. $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = 0$. However, since $f'(x)=3x^2+3^x \ln (x)>0$, we have a contradiction. Thus $a=b$.

But I'm not sure how to prove that $f'(c)>0$. Alternatively, I can prove uniqueness in another way.

Edit: Nevermind. $f'(x)=3x^2+3^x \ln (3)$.

Comment: The derivative of $x^3+3^x$ is $3x^2+\ln(3)3^x$, not $3x^2+\ln(x)3^x$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you! The proof is trivial now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $x^3+3^x$ is $3x^2+\ln(3)3^x$, not $3x^2+\ln(x)3^x$. Note that the latter function isn't even *defined* for all real numbers, since $dom(\ln)=(0,\infty)$. And even on its domain, $3x^2+\ln(x)3^x$ is frequently negative: take $x$ very small and positive. Then $3x^2$ is small and positive, and $3^x$ is slightly larger than $1$; but $\ln(x)$ is large and negative.